# Count the number of matches of a particular character in a string matched by a regex wildcard

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, awk

Can I keep a count of each different character matched in the regex *itself* ?

Suppose the regex goes looks like `/>(.*)[^a]+/`

Can I keep a count of the occurrences of, say the letter `p` in the string captured by the group `(.*)`?

Answer (score 5):

You would have to capture the string matched and process it separately.

This code demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '> plantagenetgoosewagonattributes';

if ($str =~ />(.*)[^a]+/) {
  my $substr = $1;
  my %counts;
  $counts{$_}++ for $substr =~ /./g;
  print "'$_' - $counts{$_}\n" for sort keys %counts;
}
```

**output**

```
' ' - 1
'a' - 4
'b' - 1
'e' - 4
'g' - 3
'i' - 1
'l' - 1
'n' - 3
'o' - 3
'p' - 1
'r' - 1
's' - 1
't' - 5
'u' - 1
'w' - 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Outside of the regex :

```
my $p_count = map /p/g, />(.*)[^a]/;
```

Self-contained:

```
local our $p_count;
/
   (?{ 0 })
   >
   (?: p (?{ $^R + 1 })
   |   [^p]
   )*
   [^a]
   (?{ $p_count = $^R; })
/x;
```

In both cases, you can easily expand this to count all letters. For example,

```
my %counts;
if (my ($seq = />(.*)[^a]/) {
   ++$counts{$_} for split //, $seq;
}

my $p_count = $counts{'p'};
```

Comment: Try to run your 'self-contained' code outside Perl :) (sed, awk, bash - see author tags). ;) Don't mess the ability to run some perl code inside 'extended' syntax of Regexp with regexp itself.

Comment: @mvf, It's impossible* to write a problem that runs in all those interpreters, so that makes no sense. (* -- You could write a "quine", but that would involve writing the program in multiple languages too.)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you can't. You can only capture some group by parentheses and later check the length of data captured by that group.

Comment: It's even possible to do completely within the regex. See my answer.

Comment: A "AFAIK" answer in the negative is basically always a bad posting choice. If you can't explain why it is impossible, why tell them you think it is?

Comment: @Borodin I was also surprised by the number of upvotes, what's  why i upvoted you comment :)  But question was 'can I', and short and correct answer is 'you can't'. The number of upvotes, and absence of other sensible answers prove this is the only good answer :)

Comment: And, @Mark, what's why i added AFAIK. I know it well, andi have a big expirience in that field, and I'm sure in my answer but it's hard to prove. BUT i'm always opened to know more, and if author of regexp library will tell me - 'yap, that feature exists, but I've forgot to document it', i'll change my mind :) Explaining why certain things are imposiible - is too hard. Try to explain me why people can't fly, for example. You can cite whole handbook about mechanics, but even after that how can you be sure? :)

Answer (score 3):

Going along the lines of Borodin's solution , here is a pure bash one :

```
let count=0  
testarray=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) 

string="> plantagenetgoosewagonattributes"                 # the string 
pattern=">(.*)[^a]+"                                   # regex pattern

limitvar=${#testarray[@]}                                  #array length

[[ $string =~ $pattern ]] && 
( while [ $count -lt $limitvar ] ; do sub="${BASH_REMATCH[1]//[^${testarray[$count]}]}" ; echo "${testarray[$count]} = ${#sub}" ; ((count++)) ; done )
```

Staring from bash 3.0 , bash has introduced the capture groups which can be accessed through BASH_REMATCH[n].

The Solution declares the characters to be counted as arrays [ Check out `declare -a` for array declaraton in complex cases] .A single character count would require   no count variables ,no while construct but a variable for the character instead of an array .

If you are including ranges as in the code above , this array declaration does the exact thing .

```
testarray=(`echo {a..z}`)
```

An introduction of an `if`
loop will account for the display of `0` count characters . I wanted to keep the solution as simple as possible .

Answer (score 2):

There is the experimental, don't-use-me, `(?{ code })` construct...

From `man perlre`:

> "(?{ code })"
>    WARNING: This extended regular expression feature is considered experimental, and may be
>    changed without notice. Code executed that has side effects may not perform identically
>    from version to version due to the effect of future optimisations in the regex engine.

If that didn't scare you off, here's an example that counts the number of "p"s

```
my $p_count;
">pppppbca" =~ /(?{ $p_count = 0 })>(p(?{$p_count++})|.)*[^a]+/;
print "$p_count\n";
```

Comment: Yields an incorrect result because you didn't account for backtracking. (Should return 4 for `ppppp` and `pppppa`, but returns 5.)

Comment: Also, using `my` variables declared outside of `(?{ })` inside of `(?{ })` will lead to incorrect results in some situations. Use `local our` instead of `my`.

Comment: Both good points. I admit I never used the feature until I tried writing this example. I did see the note about using local to handle backtracking. I'm not sure why I posted this answer; I wouldn't recommend using this, but thought it was interesting enough to point out.

Answer (score 0):

First a remark: Due to the greediness of *, the last `[^a]+` will never match more than one non-a character -- i.e., you might as well drop the `+`.

And as @mvf said, you need to capture the string that the wildcard matches to be able to count the characters in it. Perl regular expressions do not have a way to return a count of how many times a specific group matches -- the engine probably keeps the number around to support the `{,n}` mechanism, but you can't get at it.